# List all values based on condition and date range in excel

Tags: excel

Example and result i would like it to be:

[image]

I have three data columns

Customer name Campaign Number and Date

I would like to draw all Campaign Number that related to a customer with selected date range like in the picture.

The result will be shown from G7 downwards.

What will  be the excel formula I need to put in Cell G7 to achieve the result i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option you could apply:

[image]

The formula I used in `H2` would translate to:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,AGGREGATE(15,3,((($A$2:$A$6=$F$4)/($A$2:$A$6=$F$4))*(($C$2:$C$6>=$F$2)/($C$2:$C$6>=$F$2))*(($C$2:$C$6<=$F$3)/($C$2:$C$6<=$F$3))*ROW($A$1:$A$6)),ROWS($H$2:H2))),"")`

Another option could be to work from bottom to top:

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,LARGE(($A$2:$A$6=$F$4)*($C$2:$C$6>=$F$2)*($C$2:$C$6<=$F$3)*ROW($A$2:$A$6),ROWS($G$2:G2))-1),"")}`

Notice to enter this as an array formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

With sheet references it looks like:

`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6,LARGE((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6=Sheet1!$F$4)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6>=Sheet1!$F$2)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6<=Sheet1!$F$3)*ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6),ROWS($G$2:G2))-1),"")}`

Comment: The second formula seems easy to understand  however it got some syntax error when i Ctrl Shift Enter

Comment: Excuse me, left a semicolon in the formula. Lost in translation :) Edited!

Comment: would this work if i put this formular in another sheet? because I tried in the same sheet it works, but i copied it to another sheet and changing the sheet reference... but i did not work?

Comment: Should work, just step through and evaluate your formula. You are probably missing on or two sheet references. See edit.